# How to make GET Request with api key in LUA

Tags: google-sheets, lua, google-sheets-api

I am trying to get a request from Google Sheet API, but I don't know how to pass API key in code.

```
local http = require("socket.http")
local body, code, headers, status = http.request("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1AQK1WHGsavVmhNugAipMsrweB3m25xp01vtzGA8BvwE/values/Global!A1:D5")
print(code, status, body)
```

right now I'm getting Error 403

Comment: I believe you need to use http Post with the api key in a field named Key: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it at the end of the URL as a query parameter, like this:

```
 http.request("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[spreadsheet-id]/values/Global!A1:D5?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]")
```

For next time, you could check how Sheets API [1] makes a request by clicking in the expand icon on "Try this API" window after you make a request from there.

[1] https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get